# Why values from C# getting stored twice in the sql server database?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database

This problem occurs when I run my aplication. Express profiler shows that connection to database occurs twice, so problem is in the code!

Code Sample Where I define what to send is here.

```
label_Map.Text = message.Substring(21, 3);
                label_Sys.Text = message.Substring(15, 3);
                label_Dia.Text = message.Substring(18, 3);
                label_Pulse.Text = message.Substring(26, 3);

                //System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"D:\String.txt", label_Sys.Text);
                //System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"D:\String.txt", label_Dia.Text);
                //System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"D:\String.txt", label_Pulse.Text);

                SaveData(

               message.Substring(15, 3),
               message.Substring(18, 3),   
               message.Substring(26, 3)
                    //label_Sys.Text,
                    //label_Dia.Text,
                    //label_Pulse.Text
```

And Sending Code here

```
 private void SaveData(string sys, string dia, string pulse)
    {
        try
        {
            string connectionString = @"Data Source=PlUTO-PC\;Initial Catalog=merisana;Integrated Security=True";
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))


            {

               // connection.Open();
                string queryString = "INSERT INTO dbo.merisana_test (sys, dia, pulse) VALUES (@sys, @dia, @pulse)";
                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);
                //command.CommandText = string.Format("INSERT INTO merisana1 (sys, dia, pulse) VALUES ({0}, {1}, {2})", sys, dia, pulse);


                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sys", sys);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dia", dia);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pulse", pulse);

                command.Connection.Open();
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }

    }
```

Full Code Here https://www.dropbox.com/s/4oitl0p3ldcfo79/Form1.cs?v=0swn-

Comment: Set a breakpoint and step through your code to see what it's doing.

Comment: debug & log: set break point in `SaveData` method and count how many time the method is hit. Is this an ASP.NET app or desktop app?

Comment: Are you perhaps calling the method twice?

Comment: Can't get to your dropbox due to work big brother filters, but probably whatever event your top code snippet is from, is being called twice.  The code you've pasted looks fine.

Comment: `System.Diagnostics.Debug.Writeline()` is your friend

Comment: Downvoted because you really just need to just step through your code and watch exactly when things occur. If you cannot attach your debugger for any reason then try logging to a file, or even message box pop-ups.

Comment: Thans you for advice, Im new in C#, and this is my school project, where I use aplication, which has been written before me. So Im strugling with it right now..

Answer (score 1):

You need to debug this code:

```
string buffer = "";

private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
  while (serialPort1.BytesToRead > 0)
  {
    buffer += serialPort1.ReadTo("\r");

    int index1 = buffer.IndexOf('\u0002');
    int index2 = buffer.IndexOf('\u0003', index1 + 1);
    string buf = "";
    if ((index1 >= 0) && (index2 > index1))
    {
      buf = buffer.Substring(index1 + 1, (index2 - 1 - index1));
      buffer = buffer.Remove(index1, (index2  - index1));
      this.BeginInvoke(new displayDeleg(display), new object[] { buf });
    }
  }
}
```

Your save method is being called from the display method, and clearly this can be called more than once since you are in a while loop.

Answer (score 0):

100% sure you are calling the method twice, try posting your front code.
From code behing you are just calling once, but maybe the behabiour of the buttons make it happen twice.
Also, when creating functions for database queries, try to return an int instead of make it void, so you will be able to keep track of this things.
Also, set a breakpoint and see how many times you call `SaveData`

Would like to put this like a comment but I cant, sorry